# How to send multiple payments in single click using paypal api?

Tags: api, paypal

For e.g:- 100% payment will go to admin’s account. A automatic transaction will be performed where admin will see total revenue next to which a button will be located. Clicking on which, will perform the automatic transaction online and after the deduction of admin’s commission rest of the amount will be transferred to other user's(Can be 2 or 3 users) account.

Answer (score 0):

You might look for "Chained Payments" https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/adaptive-payments/integration-guide/APIntro/